# How to close modal after transition to another modal on angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm using [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to open modals.

I have two states with modals:

1. `'modal.first'`
2. `'modal.second'`

**What I want is to close the first modal by button click and change state to `'modal.second'`.**

The problem is that i can only close modal **or** change state (but first modal still open).

Here state definitions:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('modal.first', {
        url: '/first',
        onEnter: function ($state, $modal) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'some_url',
                controller: 'FirstCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    //...
                }
                            }
            }).result.finally(function () {
                $state.go('^');
            });
        }
    })
```

The second modal definition is all the same (with state name `modal.second` and url `/second`).

I'm trying to close modal (and change state) like this:

(`FirstController`)

```
$scope.goSecond = function () {
    $state.go('modal.second', $stateParams);
    $modalInstance.close();
};
```

But this didn't work. I able to choose only one - or `$state.go(...)`, or `$modalInstance.close()`.

I think maybe i should take more attention to the `.finally()` block. But still have no ideas. Thanks.

Link to the official FAQ with modals: [click](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state)

**UPDATE** I cannot just change state in finally without any statements, because I'm need to change state only by clicking the button (and make `.go('^')` in any other cases).

Comment: If possible then can you replicate this in fiddle or plunker ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define service, which hold modalInstance and close it if is open called again.

```
angular.module('someModule')
  .service("singleModal", function($modal) {
    this.modalInstance = null;
    this.open = function(options) {
      if (this.modalInstance) {
        this.modalInstance.close();
      }

      this.modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
      return this.modalInstance;
    };
  })
```

You can see simple example of service (without ui bootstrap) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zz7JherD0oQfLpxHRxgn?p=preview)